# PyQT Signals doesn't works on Windows

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a Python application using PyQT4 to build the GUI, on Linux works fine, but on Windows the signals aren't being received :/

My code is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
from dlgContador import Ui_dlgContador
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from funciones.archivosOps import archivosOps


class ArchivosGui(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.archivo=None
        self.app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.mainWindow=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.mainWindow.setupUi(self)
        self.__connectFunctions()
        self.setWindowTitle("Editor de Texto")
        self.show()
        self.app.exec_()


    pass

   def __connectFunctions(self):
    self.connect(self.mainWindow.actionAbrir,QtCore.SIGNAL("activated()"), self.abrir)
    self.connect(self.mainWindow.actionContar_Palabras,QtCore.SIGNAL("activated()"),self.info)
    self.connect(self.mainWindow.actionGuardar,QtCore.SIGNAL("activated()"),self.guardar)
    self.connect(self.mainWindow.actionGuardarComo,QtCore.SIGNAL("activated()"),self.guardarComo)
    pass
```

What i'm doing wrong ? :/

Comment: `__connectFunctions()` is outside the class, is that a copy paste error or is it like that in your code?

Comment: wow i hadn't noticed. .. nope i'm reading some articles about develop  using pyqt but no isn't a copy paste.

Comment: it's a problem pasting the code on the question, on my source the method is in the class

Comment: What is the type of those (`self.mainWindow.actionAbrir` etc.)? The name suggests `QAction`. If that is the case, `QAction` doesn't have `activated` signal.

Comment: hmm it's weird because on the QT Designer for Linux  has an `activated` signal and works.. i have changed to `triggered` and works fine :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On QTDesigner for linux the QTAction haves a signal called "Activated()" and works only on Linux, my be is depercated.

Just need change "activated()" to "triggered()" and will work fine